# i am getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, database

```
// insert value using add buttons

btnadd.onclick= (event)=>{
    
let flag = bulkcreate(db.products, {
        
custname: custname.value,
        
items: items.value,
        
name: proname.value,
        
seller: seller.value,
        
price: price.value
 
   });
}
```

when I write this code then In console give an error is main.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick of null
why this error come plz help me to find a solution

Comment: try wrapping it in a `window.onload= function() { // your code }`

Answer (score 1):

This is because you need to create the button, get a reference to it, then pass it to your code

in your html

```
<button type="button" id="btn_add">Add</button>
```

Then is your JS, consider using this inside a page load event:

```
var btnadd = document.getElementById("btn_add");

btnadd.onclick= (event)=>{
    
let flag = bulkcreate(db.products, {
        
custname: custname.value,
        
items: items.value,
        
name: proname.value,
        
seller: seller.value,
        
price: price.value
 
   });
}
```

Comment: Problem was not solved same error are come

Comment: I would need to know what line and what code is on this line, or all of the code  main.js:25 Uncaught TypeError: